# Upsert fields must be defined as unique External ID fields in Salesforce - Heroku Connect

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-connect

I got this error:

`Error:Read-write mappings require an upsert field for syncing. Upsert fields must be defined as unique External ID fields in Salesforce.More Info...
Warning:Fields needed for insertion to Salesforce need to be mapped: LastName`

after changing plan from Developer to Professional when creating mapping in Heroku for Contact object.

Even after chaning to plan higher than Professional, the same error appears.

It was possible with Developer plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an Upsert operation, you can either specify the Salesforce record Id as the unique identifier, or you can specify a custom field.  If you use a custom field, then that field must be marked as Unique inside Salsesforce.  You can do this by going to Setup and editing the field.  There's a checkbox to mark it as Unique and as an External Id.

Also, it looks like you're not populating all required fields, specifically: LastName on the Contact.